# Access server side recordset from the client side VBScript

Tags: vbscript, server

I have server side recordset `rsPerson` and a HTML input `txtName`.

I am trying to compare the value from the record set to the value currently in the input, to see if it has changed. If it has, I am setting another variable for future use.

But, I am facing difficulty in accessing the server side variable on the client side.

Here is my code.

```
If <%rsPerson.Fields("Name").Value%> <> document.all("txtName").Value Then
    'Do Something Here
End If
```

But, I am getting something like End Of statement error in VBScript. I tried putting the entire if condition with the `<%%>`, but that too did not work.

I know I probably can use some server side variable to store the value from the recordset. But, am I doing something wrong in code? Why can't I use server side recordset directly?

Comment: Your code sample is ASP code, which doesn't work on the client-side. And you can't use server-side variables from the client, because for that to work the variable would have to exist in the same process as the client code. To be able to do what you're asking you need to read the recordset from the server into a recordset on the client. Whether or not that's a sensible thing to do I can't say with what little information you provided.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.The variable does exist in the same process.I thought using <%%> was a way to access server side variables.Just that using the recessed directly gives me problems,while reading the same recordset into a server side variable and then accessing the same server side variable from the client side gives me no issues.

Comment: You can't access server-side variables from a client-side process, because they exist in the server-side process, not in the client-side process. Please clarify where your code actually runs. And also show how the variables are populated, plus the complete, unaltered error messages.

Comment: It's painfully obvious that you don't understand server <--> client architecture.

Comment: I might have to read up on the client server architecture.I solved my issue by declaring a variable to hold the record set value and then accessing it using <%%>